# MySQL - exception

Tags: java, mysql

tudo bem?

Estou estudando Java e estou com problemas para conectar em um banco MySql, abaixo trecho da exception gerada:

```
conectando ...
nov 06, 2019 4:32:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [br.com.caelum.servlet.AdicionaContatoServlet] in context with path [/fj21-agenda] threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/fj21
    at br.com.caelum.agenda.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:22)
    at br.com.caelum.agenda.dao.ContatoDao.<init>(ContatoDao.java:20)
    at br.com.caelum.servlet.AdicionaContatoServlet.service(AdicionaContatoServlet.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/fj21
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at br.com.caelum.agenda.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:20)
    ... 25 more



package br.com.caelum.agenda;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ConnectionFactory {

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("conectando ...");

        /*try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new SQLException(e);
        } */

        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/fj21", "root", "root123");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Os serviços do MySql estão ativos, porém quando tento fazer o cadastro de alguns dados no banco aparece o erro acima. Poderiam me ajudar com este erro?

Obrigado!